# importing angular services with ES6 and webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm trying to import $timeout with ES6 and webpack and I keep getting that $timeout is undefined.
Can anyone help?
If there's a way that doesn't involve using $inject I'd prefer it because I'm gradually trying to get rid of angularjs in my code.

randomTVNames.service.js:

```
import angular from 'angular';

class RandomTVNames {
    constructor($timeout) {
        this.tv = ['Shield', 'Walking Dead', 'Castle', 'Leftovers'];
        this.timeout = $timeout;
        console.log(this.timeout);
    }

    getName() {
        const totalNames = this.tv.length;
        const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalNames);
        return this.tv[rand];
    }

    getTimeout(){

        this.timeout(function () {
            alert("this is timeout")}, 3000);
    }
}

RandomTVNames.$inject = ['$timeout'];

//todo - try to inject angular argument (such as $timeout) with $inject
var randomTVNames = new RandomTVNames();

export default randomTVNames;
```

home.controller.js:

```
import randomTVNames from '../../services/randomTVNames.service';
import mainModule from '../../mainModule';

class HomeController {
    constructor() {
        this.tv = randomTVNames;
        this.name = 'World';
    }

    randomTVName($timeout) {
        this.name = this.tv.getName();
    }

    getCtrlTimeout(){
        this.tv.getTimeout();
    }

}

mainModule.controller('HomeController', HomeController);
```

Comment: Are you minifying your code?

Comment: `$timeout` is not going to inject itself. What do you expect when you call the constructor of `RandomTVNames` without any argument?

Comment: you mean like this: "var randomTVNames = new RandomTVNames($timeout);"?  because I still get that $timeout is undefined

Answer (score 2):

ES6 modules are not compatible with the module system from Angular 1.x. This means that `export`ing and `import`ing services and controllers won't work, you need to register and inject them using Angular's module system.

randomTVNames.service.js:

```
import mainModule from '../../mainModule';

class RandomTVNames {
    // ... snip ...
}

RandomTVNames.$inject = [ /* ... snip ... */ ];

mainModule.service('randomTVNames', RandomTVNames);
```

home.controller.js:

```
import mainModule from '../../mainModule';

class HomeController {
    constructor($scope, randomTVNames) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.tv = randomTVNames;
    }
}

HomeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'randomTVNames'];

mainModule.controller('HomeController', HomeController);
```

Then in your main webpack file, make sure to import both of them so they get bundled:

```
import 'services/randomTVNames.service';
import 'controllers/controller.service';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Do you mean that there's no way of using $timeout or $scope for example with ES6?  I tried what you suggested and I get "timeout is not a function".

Comment: That sounds like it's a different error with the way you have the strings in your `$inject` array set up. The `$inject` property tells the angular module loader that it needs to call your services, controllers, etc with the right objects. General rules of thumb: if you want to use `$timeout` and `$scope`, you need to name them in an `$inject` array. Any function that uses `$inject` should **not** be `export`ed or `import`ed, but should be passed to the module using mainModule.service(), mainModule.controller(), et al.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get rid of $inject, unless you are not minifying you code (but i hope you are).

Angular is injecting variables using their names, so when it sees $scope, it know to look for it and inject it, but when minifying your code the variable names are changed ($scope becomes c etc.) and angular does not know what object you want to inject.

That is what $inject is for since strings are not minified.

Comment: thanks for your help but it doesn't work even with $inject.  It was commented out in the original question, i fixed it.

Comment: try putting $inject = ['$timeout']; above the contructor

Comment: Don't put 'RandomTVNames.$inject = ['$timeout'];' just '$inject = ['$timeout'];'

Comment: it says $inject is not defined

Comment: Sorry, it should be: static $inject = ['$timeout']

Comment: I don't think you can write that (I get an error anyway)

Comment: You can, and you should, I think the problem is you are not using typescript modules. Anyway, try generating the code without minifying and look at it, you should get a better idea of whats going on

Comment: @fatman The question is not about typescript, and static properties are an experimental proposal and the question says ES6.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at [this loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-annotate-loader). it helps with what you're trying to do. but mind adding 'ngInject' anywhere in your js file, that injects anything